# Eway Payment Gateway Not work in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-gateway

I have integrated `eWay Payment gateway` in Magento 2.3.

It has been installed successfully. I did the settings in the admin as well. But I cannot see that `eway payment` option on the frontend checkout page. I tried to install the plugin with a default Magento 2.3 but there is also the same issue.

Can you please help me to figure this out?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: you can check the error log maybe you can find some hints about the problem. also you can try checking your browser's console log for errors as well

Comment: Have you confirmed with developer extension is compatible with 2.3

Comment: I cannot see any error.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Eway Payment extension https://marketplace.magento.com/eway-eway-rapid-magento2.html using composer to clear project magento 2.3.1 and after having set sandbox data setting the payment method has been added to the checkout page.
[image]

but as I noticed after installing with composer was intalling optional 6 extnesion
[image]

Please make sure you have all the additional packages (which are shown in the picture) that are required for correct installed eWay Payment extension to project.
And since this payment method works correctly on a pure version of Magento 2.3.1, it means that in you project layer checkout_index_index.xml can be changed.

Comment: Ok, Installed the plugin with command line and follow of your process but still it's not showing.

Comment: I can see this error: {"error":"Error happened when getting access code, please try again later"}

Comment: When this error executed on the checkout page? or specify when it is happening, page or event